# How to retrieve user posts one by one PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a social network that allows users to write posts. When the users write posts the go into my DB. When I want to show the posts they show. But they all show up in the same div. How do I make the posts show up one by one like a Facebook post in my div ? And if the user writes a long post how do I make the div expand ?

[image: Posts image]

profile.php:

```
<div id="rcorners2">
<?php

error_reporting(0);

include("connect.php");
include("auth_login.php");

$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';
  $username = trim(isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : $username);

//Write the query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = '" . $username. "' ORDER BY post_id DESC ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<p>".$row['body']. "</p>";        

}
}
else {

}
?>
</div>
```

third.css:

```
#rcorners2 {
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
padding: 20px;
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: It's more html, css, js question than it is php

Comment: I fixed it @bakero98

Comment: put ith here your fixed code it will be more advantageous to others. And you can increase your batches.

Comment: @Dhanushkasasanka What ?

Comment: if you solve this problem from yourself.put here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to open / close the **rcorners2** div inside the **while loop**.

At the moment, your code is saying that inside the first **rcorners2** you have open, to add a paragraph with the database data. So, instead this:

```
echo "<p>".$row['body']. "</p>";
```

Open and close the **rcorners2** div, because each post should be inside of it own div. Also, you may remove the old code, where you're opening and closing the div.

Comment: I don't get what you said. Where should I open and close `rcorners2`